# Why this isn't working? Find the points of the line $r$ that has the distance $\sqrt{\frac{14}{3}}$ from line $s$.

Tags: linear-algebra, geometry, analytic-geometry

I have the line 
$$r:\\x+y=2\\x=y+z$$

and 
$$s:x=y=z+1$$

I need to find the points of $r$ that has distance  $\sqrt{\frac{14}{3}}$ from $s$.

**What I tried:**

By using the formula for distance of a point to a line:

$$d(P,l) = \frac{||\vec{AP}\times\vec v||}{||\vec v||}$$
where $\vec v$ is a direction vector to the line.
I've choose the point $(1,1,0)$ from $s$, and a generic point from $r$ has the form:

$$x = \lambda\\y = 2-\lambda\\z = -2+2\lambda$$
(I don't know if this is rigth, I just choose $z=\lambda$ in the equations for $r$ and got this).
So the vector $\vec{AP}=(1-\lambda, -1+\lambda,2-2\lambda)$
$$d(P,r) = \frac{||(1-\lambda, -1+\lambda,2-2\lambda)\times(1,1,0)||}{\sqrt{2}} = \sqrt{\frac{14}{3}}$$

There is no solution for $\lambda$ because the cross product gives a vector not related to $\lambda$.

**Why this isn't working, but the answer given below Works?**

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Let $P(t, 2-t, 2t-2)$ be a general point on r.

A vector parallel to s is given by $\vec{b}=\langle1,1,1\rangle$, and a vector parallel to r is given by $\vec{a}=\vec{QP}=\langle t-1,1-t,2t-2\rangle$ where $Q=(1,1,0)$ is on both r and s.

Then $\vec{a}\times\vec{b}=\langle 3-3t,t-1,2t-2\rangle$, and the distance between r and s is given by

$d=\displaystyle\frac{\left|\vec{a}\times\vec{b}\right|}{\left|\vec{b}\right|}=\frac{\sqrt{14(t-1)^2}}{\sqrt{3}}=\frac{\sqrt{14}}{\sqrt{3}}\left|t-1\right|$,

so $\displaystyle d=\frac{\sqrt{14}}{\sqrt{3}}\iff t=0$ or $t=2$ $\iff P=(0,2,-2)$ or $P=(2,0,2)$.

---

Alternate solution:

Let $P(t, 2-t, 2t-2)$ be a general point on r and let $\vec{b}=\langle1,1,1\rangle$ be a direction vector for s as above,

and let $\vec{a}=\vec{QP}=\langle t, 2-t, 2t-1\rangle$ where $Q=(0,0,-1)$ is a point on s.

By the Pythagorean Theorem,

$\displaystyle d^2=|\vec{a}|^2-(\text{comp}_{\vec{b}}\vec{a})^2=\vec{a}\cdot\vec{a}-\frac{(\vec{a}\cdot\vec{b})^2}{\vec{b}\cdot\vec{b}}=t^2+(2-t)^2+(2t-1)^2-\frac{(2t+1)^2}{3}$, so

$\displaystyle d^2=\frac{14}{3}\iff 3(6t^2-8t+5)-(4t^2+4t+1)=14\iff 14t^2-28t=0$

$\iff14t(t-2)=0\iff t=0$ or $t=2$ $\iff P=(0,2,-2)$ or $P=(2,0,2)$.

Comment: Shouldn't $\vec b$ be equal to $(1,1,1)$? I don't know how you got $(1,1,-1)$.

Comment: Also, how did you find the general point for $r$? I've found a different one :(

Comment: You're right; my $\vec{b}$ has a sign error, so I will correct this.  For a general point on r, I used $y=2-x$ and $z=x-y=2x-2$.

Comment: Why you used a point that lies in both lines? This is confusing me a lot! And why didn't you consider $\vec a$ to be a point of $r$, but $s$?

Comment: Also, why the exercise asks for the distance between two lines that intercept? Shouldn't the distance be $0$?

Comment: It just happened that Q was on both lines; I just needed it to be on s.  The exercise is not asking for the distance between the lines, because (as you say) that is 0.  (It's asking for the points on r which are a given distance from s.)  I will include an alternate solution as well.